# How to start a ruby-tk project?

Tags: ruby, user-interface

I am learning `ruby-tk`right now and I started my project using `bundle gem my_app` because I wanted to be able to use a `Gemfile`. However there is not a proper main file. Is there a command to initialize a `ruby-tk` project ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

What operating system are you using?  Mac OS, I believe, has it already and should not require a command.

Have you checked:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_tk_guide.htm?

Comment: I am on osx, yes. Yes I did. But I was more looking for something like bundle gem. Which would create a folder structure to build my project. With a main file and libraries, etc... I m coming from Java so I was expected some folders and a main file.

Comment: I used bundle gem so far but you cant do like rake start or rake run. To start a main file. Right now my main is my test files. But I feel it's a hack more than the proper way to do it.

Comment: Probably would help if you posted your physical code so others could see it and get an idea?  Have you tried `gem install bundler`, add your desired gems, then `bundle install`?

Comment: I started my project using `bundle gem my_app`, as said in my question, but I can't start the project. I am coming from java development and in java you have a main method which is being call when you start the project. With the ruby gem structure, there is no such main file. I don't know how to start the project. Or at least what would be the proper file structure to start it.

Comment: I wonder if you could copy over or run your project within a standard RoR start-up?  Your structure of files, if I am understanding correctly, would be potentially available then.  Or you could copy over the organization to your project?  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html  Sorry I could not be of more help.

Comment: I looked into having an actual RoR project and having the browser as the UI but there are some limitation which I don't like. Like GPU usage or UDP sockets.